# addSeries method in Dojo Stacked Line Chart not working in a for loop

Tags: charts, dojo

While creating a dynamic stacked Line chart in Dojo, i use Chart object's addSeries() method with response (JSON array). When I add three addSeries method invocations, the three charts get created as expected. following code doesn't work in Dojo Stacked Line Chart.

```
chart.addSeries("data1",response,{color: "red"});
chart.addSeries("data2", response.data[1],{color: "green"});
chart.addSeries("data3", response.data[0],{color: "blue"});
```

But when I try to automate these calls through a for loop, somehow all lines on the chart get overshadowed by the last invocation of addSeries method. Thus only one line gets displayed. Following is my for loop code

```
for(var i =0 ; i<length ; i++) { 

     chart.addSeries(response.legend,response.data[i],{color: colorArray[i]});
     alert(chartData[i]);

}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the error hits you at the loop because the first parameter to addSeries method response.legend doesn't get changed during the iteration of loop. And hence your data is getting overlapped. In the last iteration, only last line of chart will be printed. You could either append the parameter response.limit with i so that on each iteration, it may get changed.

Comment: yes Buddy..now i got,legend is to be in an array or different for all..Thanks

Comment: but here i am not getting the actual data, the first ever data is current then after next(each increment in loop) is the sum of current and previous data.